# Component array returned by getComponents() method can be changed

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, visibility

I'm trying to set a pressed button invisible and set the rest visible. I used `getComponents()` method to get the three buttons and change its visibility state but something goes wrong.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Component button = ((Component) e.getSource());

    for (Component component : view.getComponents()) {
        if (component instanceof JButton) {
            if (component.getName().equals(button.getName())) {
                System.out.format("Pressed button: %s%n", button.getName());
                component.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                component.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }

    java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();

    view.revalidate();

    for (Component component : view.getComponents()) {
        System.out.format("%s is visible: %s%n", component.getName(), component.isVisible());
    }
}
```

I've used `format()` methods to get components visibility state. After launch the program buttons doesn't disappear but states are correct.

If I use `button` variable to set its visibility state it runs successfully but I can't change the rest of the buttons visibility state.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm triying to set a pressed button invisible

You have the button that was clicked so just make it invisible.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Component button = ((Component) e.getSource());
    button.setVisible(false);
    java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
}
```

There is no need to iterate through all the buttons on the panel.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't meant that. There are three buttons and only one might be invisible.